# Replace a function doing document.write with another

Tags: javascript, dom

I have following script tag where a function A() does a document.write(). I don't have access to A() since it's from third part script.

```
//block1
<script type="text/javascript">
    A();
</script>
```

I don't have any id/class hook to block1 but I can introduce a function call before A() like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     B();
     A();
</script>
```

I want B() function to replace block1 to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     C();
</script>    
// or keep as is
<script type="text/javascript">
     A();
</script>
```

Is this possible and how should I go about it?

Answer (score 4):

If you can insert code after `A()` is defined, but before it is called (might not be possible), then you can redefine `A()` like you would define any other function in JavaScript.

If that is not possible, you can redefine `document.write` before `A()` gets called, and then undo that after `A()` gets called.  For example:

```
var write = document.write;
document.write = function(s)
{
    //do nothing, or whatever you want
    console.log(s);
}
//then, after A(), just do:
document.write = write;
```

Comment: +1 this is kinda useful. Although one issue is B() might replace the block with A(). In above example, A() will be called again which I don't want.

Comment: thanks wsanville , this was really useful for some script I was using that was copying and replacing a html block that had a document.write in it. fixed now after seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can monkey-patch A instead?

```
A = C;
```

This will change all future calls to A to call C instead. This might or might not be what you want.

Comment: thanks for chipping in. A() is called multiple times on the page, hence rules this out.

Comment: Is it recursively called though? There is also the possibility of doing `oldA = A; A = C; A(); A = oldA`

Comment: +1 It's not but I can't remove A(); and can only add B();. Above solution will make it execute twice.